# Cidades com o mesmo nome utilizando GeoCharts

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-charts, geolocalização

Estou realizando um projeto, utilizando GeoCharts, como estou trabalhando todos os municípios de todo o brasil, tem algumas cidades com o mesmo nome, quando vou mostrar essas cidades, elas aparecem no estado errado, alguém já passou por esse problema? Na foto a seguir, estou buscando todas as cidades do estado do Pernambuco, e verifiquei as cidades que estão em outro estado, é aquelas que tem o mesmo nome, exemplo no RS. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, utilizei um **concat(municipios.nome,' ' ,municipios.uf)** no arquivo PHP que gerava o json. O geocharts reconhece as cidades com o mesmo nome, dizendo de qual estado ela é. Exemplo Maceió AL